# Why can't I change select option styling in IE8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, html-select

I wanna change font style in select-option box.

I have tested in IE6, chrome, Sapari.....it is working!

but it wasn't working in IE8

It did not working :

```
<select name="myselect">
  <option val="1" style="font-family: Nanum Gothic, sans-serif;">All</option>
  <option val="2" style="font-family: Nanum Gothic, sans-serif;">Name</option>
  <option val="3" style="font-family: Nanum Gothic, sans-serif;">Phone</option>
</select>
```

And It did not working :

```
<select name="myselect" style="font-family: Nanum Gothic, sans-serif;">
  <option val="1">All</option>
  <option val="2">Name</option>
  <option val="3">Phone</option>
</select>
```

IE8 have any bug about select-option tag?

Or It is normal?

Thanks.

Comment: `<select>` elements are "replaced elements" and therefore have limited styling capabilities. For instance, try using a `<select>` on your phone, you'll notice that it has a specific, phone-friendly interface. One that "fancy" select boxes like Select2 completely fail to reproduce.

Comment: Do you have any styling? Add this in fiddle

Comment: any reason you are still testing ie6?  Microsoft stopped supporting it in April

Comment: Beacause my business clients still use ie6. And they wanna use ie6 forever! T.T

Comment: Setting style on `option` does not work on *any* version of IE (including IE 11), whereas setting style on `select` works on all IE versions at least from IE 6. If you have observed that it does work on IE 8, re-check your test. Your code is now invalid (`val` is not a valid attribute), an although this does not affect the issue, it suggests that you may have made some other mistakes in testing. You have accepted an answer that says that “the select-styling method” is supported by IE 8, so this too suggests that the observation was mistaken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing a different cross-browser behavior. The option-styling method is *not* supported by IE8/9, Chrome18 (embedded in my editor) and FF30.

The select-styling method is supported by IE8/9 and Chrome18, but not by FF30. Test it for yourself with [**this demo**](http://jsbin.com/zufak/1/edit?html,output). Its code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select name="myselect1">
      <option val="1" style="font-family: sans-serif;">All</option>
      <option val="2" style="font-family: serif;">Name</option>
      <option val="3" style="font-family: sans-serif;">Phone</option>
    </select>

    <select name="myselect2" style="font-family: sans-serif;">
      <option val="1">All</option>
      <option val="2">Name</option>
      <option val="3">Phone</option>
    </select>

    <select name="myselect3" style="font-family: serif;">
      <option val="1">All</option>
      <option val="2">Name</option>
      <option val="3">Phone</option>
    </select>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, be aware that, like Niet The Dark Absol already implied in his comment, all styling is ignored by touchscreens. No matter which browser is used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I knew what can not ie8 change font-family in option tag. And additionally I tested that in IE11 and Chrome35, it was worked.